# How to set new user to a group automatically according to their role in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wp website I'm using WP User Group plugin (see [plugin page here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-groups/)) so that in the user admin page they are organized in three groups: teacher, student and user. The plugin works very well manually but I'd like it to work automatically.

When a user signs up and he's assigned a teacher role, he should be automatically added to the teacher group.

Any code idea?

Comment: Did you even try anything? What have you done to try and get this done other than come here and hope someone would give you the answer. Show us what you have let us help you learn, this site isn't about us just giving people the answer.

Comment: Dustin thank you for your feedback. I'm a complete newbie and don't even know where to start. If you feel I should remove the question I will be willing to do it with to problem.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but its hard for us to help without doing all the work if we are provided with nothing other than the problem. I won't say remove the question but maybe update it, tell us what you have done, what route you were taking to try and get it working, try and show us some code, even if its totally wrong we would rather see someone who is trying than someone who posts and just wants us to solve their issues, thats what people pay developers for.

Comment: That's totally understandable Dustin. I agree from every point. I don't know where to start, but I'll try to get some road and try something. If I won't come up with anything I will remove this answer since not practical. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WP User Group plugin use `user-group` `taxonomy` to save the Group. So
>   you can use [`wp_set_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to assign user to a group by
>   user_id.

Use the below code to assign user after registration:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myAssignGroup', 10, 1 );

function myAssignGroup($user_id){
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        //for teacher
        if ($role == 'teacher') {
            wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 254, 'user-group', FALSE); //by tag_ID
            //wp_set_object_terms($user_id, my-first-group, 'user-group', FALSE); //by term slug
        }
        //for student
        else if($role == 'student'){
            wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 256, 'user-group', FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**The code is tested and fully functional.**

To get the `tag_ID` or term `slug` please refer to the attached image.
[image]

Hope this helps!